# no output in DISTINCT in mysql php

Tags: mysql, distinct

I cannot display in my distinct query in mysql please help.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
mysql_select_db("sarangani");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT year(posted) AS year FROM news ORDER BY posted");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo "$row[year]";
}
?>
```

Comment: i dont have error my only output was blank. it did not display my desire output. pls help

Comment: Change php.ini file : display_error = On and error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED (then restart your web server) and tell us what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure the query should deliver a result, you need to use the proper way to `echo` out the result:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['year']; // So don't put it inside double quotes
}
```

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday What do you mean "nothing"? You need to be as specific as possible. What do you want, and what are you getting?

Comment: Then your query probably doesn't deliver a result or there is an error along the way. Several things you can try: 1° change your code so that errors are shown (search SO for this) - 2° what happens if you run the query directly in the db?

Comment: i want to display years stored in database, and i dont know what is wrong on my code. im getting blank result. it did not display the result.